# Can I install IBMMQ client in Windows Container ? Best option to move Windows Console App (using IBM MQ client) to Windows Container

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to move one .NET framework 4.5 Windows console app to Windows Container. That app is using IBM MQ client 9.0.0.6. The application is working fine local Machine/VDI where I have installed IBM MQ 9.0.0.6 Client successfully.

What will be the best approach to move this app to Windows Container ?

I have followed below options but it's not working.

Install the whole IBM MQ 9.0.0.6 Client in Windows Container using silent installation. But I can see the logs saying it's installed successfully but my application is not working fine. During connecting to QManager, I am getting below error.
{"The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ' threw an exception."}

Silent Installation Command in Windows Container: msiexec /i "c:\temp\Windows\MSI\IBM MQ.msi" /l*v c:\temp\install.log /q TRANSFORMS="1033.mst" AGREETOLICENSE="yes" ADDLOCAL="Client"

Second Option, I am trying to use the removal of IBM MQ client dependencies and only take the required dlls in my Application but it's also not working.

Also, tried to explore IBM MQ Redistributable client but seems it's not working.

But somehow I knew that any one of these options should be working. Can you please help me out on this ?

Thanks,
koushik

Comment: It appears that you are using Unamanged mode of MQ .NET. The most likely cause for "The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ' threw an exception." is that the MQ .NET library is not finding MQ C Client libraries. Have you tried using MQ Managed Client mode instead of Unmanaged? You can use MQ .NET library from Nuget and you don't need the full MQ client installation.

Comment: Thanks Sashi. I am using the same configuration in my local VDI with MQ client installed and it's working fine. But I'm getting this error when I uninstalled the client and putting all the necessary dlls in bin folder of the application.  The idea is to move my application to windows cluster without client installation.  That's why I'm trying to run the whole app without MQ client installation.  But getting the error. Can you please help me is there any alternative way to do that...i was also looking for redist mq client packages but not get enough information to proceed with.

Comment: Running in managed mode would mean you only need the `amqmdnet.dll`.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc.  If I am using the below code, _mqProperties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY]=MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED;                                                        
Then I am getting the error with error code : 2538 and Exception thrown: 'IBM.WMQ.MQException' in amqmdnet.dll.

Comment: 2538 is MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE. Check if listener has been started on the queue manager. See this: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=codes-2538-09ea-rc2538-mqrc-host-not-available

Comment: I am able to run the App in in my VDI without MQ client, Now I have moved the app to  windows cluster without IBM client installation, but now I am getting below  error message : 2539 . It seems certificate issue, since i am running  the app from cluster.   Do you have any idea why this error happens ?                                                                                                          Message:2539; InnerException:; StackTrace:  at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)
at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable properties)

Comment: Did you lookup what MQRC 2539 means?

Comment: Yes. I checked few docs but nothing useful.  After importing the cert in container level,  still its not working.  Not sure what is the issue in container level but it seems working in local vdi.

Comment: Do we have any sample working .NET framework console app solution where the Application run on windows container and able to connect ibmmq running outside container.